# Adding instance variables to objects using LinkedList Collection

Tags: java, collections

I have a Car class :

```
public class Car {

    public String name = null; // Name of the Car Model
    public String color = null; // Color of the car

    Car(){
          /** DO WHATEVER***/
    }
}
```

---

Then in the main() class I do this :

```
    LinkedList<Car> myCars = new  LinkedList<Car>();

    myCars.add(new Car());
    myCars.add(new Car());
    myCars.add(new Car());

    myCars.get(0).name = "Geep";
    myCars.get(0).color = "Black";

    myCars.get(1).name = "Camry";
    myCars.get(1).color = "Red";

    myCars.get(2).name = "Honda";
    myCars.get(2).color = "Green";
```

---

My question :

```
Lets assume that at the time of Car object creations, we do not have values of these instance variables and we get them at a later stage, so that constructor initialization is not feasible.
```

Then is this the correct way above ? I mean how instance variables of each objects would be assigned values, in Java collection.I mean, using the get() method ?   I understand, if we have lots of car
objects then we will use a for loop.

Please explain.

Thank you.

Comment: the right way in this case would be to initialize these values in the constructor of Car

Comment: @Navchetan: Can you please rephrase/elaborate on what you mean by:  "I mean how instance variables of each objects would be assigned values,
in Java collection.I mean, using the get() method ? I understand, if we have lots of car
objects then we will use a for loop."

Comment: Yes I understand. But lets say, that at the object creation time we do not have the instance variable values, and we get them at the later stage. And there are around 50+ instance variable per object. Then is this the right and optimum way : myCars.get(0).name = "Geep"; myCars.get(0).color = "Black"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would make more sense to change the constructor from: `/** DO WHATEVER***/`

to something like:

```
Car(String name, String color){
    this.name = name;
    this.color = color;
}
```

and later on to the insertion into the list:

```
myCars.add(new Car("Geep", "Black"));
myCars.add(new Car("Camry", "red"));
...
```

In case you don't have "the details" of the cars, and you simply need to instantiate a list with 50 cars and later on "add the details" - another question raises: where do the details come from ? if you don't know it in advance it has to come from an eternal source (user-input, file, etc) and then it would make sense to run in a loop over the list and add the details:

```
for (Car car : myCars) {
    String name = ... // get the details of the car from an external source
    String type = ... // get the details of the car from an external source
    car.setName(name); // of course you'll have to implement setName() and setType()
    car.setType(type); // which is a better practice than exposing the class members via public access
}
```

Comment: Yes I understand.  But lets say, that at the object creation time we do not have the instance variable values, and we get them at the later stage. And there are around 50+ instance variable per object. Then is this the right and optimum way :  myCars.get(0).name = "Geep";
myCars.get(0).color = "Black"

Comment: @Navchetan see addition

Comment: @alfasin +1. I would also recommend builder pattern if you have too many instance variables, makes code reusable, readable and easier to maintain IMHO. Here is a [link](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074938/core-java/too-many-parameters-in-java-methods-part-3-builder-pattern.html) with some more info on it.

Comment: @dubes the builder pattern would not fit into this scenario since the details of the objects are unknown at the time of instantiation. The pattern here is creating "blank" template Car objects and "fill in" the details later-on. In the builder pattern all the parameters are collected and only then the object is instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding whether this is the correct way: I prefer overriding the constructor so that my initialization and setter code is at the same place.

Essentially, I would provide the constructor for Car as:

```
public class Car {

public String name = null; // Name of the Car Model
public String color = null; // Color of the car

public Car(String name, String color){
  super();
  this.name = name;
  this.color = color;
  }
}
```

I would then put it in my collection as:

```
LinkedList<Car> myCars = new  LinkedList<Car>();

myCars.add(new Car("Jeep", "Black"));
myCars.add(new Car("Ferrari", "Red"));
```

Comment: Yes I understand. But lets say, that at the object creation time we do not have the instance variable values, and we get them at the later stage. And there are around 50+ instance variable per object. Then is this the right and optimum way : myCars.get(0).name = "Geep"; myCars.get(0).color = "Black"

Comment: @Navchetan understood, in such a case, I would rather try: Car c = myCars.get(0); c.setName(); etc... If you have too many instance variables per object you can also take a look at Builder Pattern. I will post a code sample and some links soon

Answer (score 0):

First, it it not recommended to expose instance variables (public). Change public to **private** and create the getters. Also, you could create a constructor that takes a name and color in parameters:

```
public class Car {

    private String name = null;
    private String color = null;

    public Car(String name, String color) {
        this.name = name;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;    
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }
}
```

Then you can do :

```
LinkedList<Car> myCars = new  LinkedList<Car>();

myCars.add(new Car("Jeep", "Black"));
myCars.add(new Car("Camry", "Red"));
myCars.add(new Car("Honda", "Green"));
```

There are many ways to do it but I would definitely set the car information before adding it to the list.